# android wait for file upload finished firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to upload file to firebase storage and get download link and use it immediately in the following code.

```
String FileLink;
StorageReference storageReference = irebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference(FileName);
storageReference.putFile(FileUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    FileLink=uri.toString();
                }
            });
        }
    })

//Wait for upload to complete and use FileLink immediately
```

Is there anyway to put the app on hold until the upload complete and link retrived?

Comment: You can hide/disable your UI elements until onSuccess is called. Not sure if that is what you meant by putting the app "on hold".

Comment: I altually mean "on hold". After the link is retrieved, I will save it to someplace else. If the file isn't uploaded and the link isn't retrived yet, it would be null.

Comment: If there is no other code your app already waits. In onSucces() you can then call the code that handles the retrieved uri. Thats all.

Comment: The rest of the code is too long and invole to others component, I can't put all in the onSuccess(). Is there anyway to put the app wait for a while or until the link is retrieved like Sleep() in C?

Comment: So you need to use the value of `FileLink` outside `onSuccess`?

Comment: Yes, is it possible to retrieved and use FileLink outside onSuccess?

Comment: You do not need to put all the code in onSuccess. Just put all the code in a sepatate function and call that function in onSuccess. The only parameter of that function would be the uri. So do away with your global variable FileLink.

Comment: Seperate function is not available for my case. Maybe I should make a "lock" waiting for the upload finished.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70178210/9473786) for some solutions. If you can use coroutines (would require extra migration) and can make the function a suspend function, you can use a coroutine to have it suspend and wait for FileLink to be set. Otherwise, you will have to move the rest of the code to a separate function that you call on `onSuccess` - these is not really any other way of handling async calls like this. If "separate function is not available" you should explain clearly in the question why you cannot make a separate function.

Comment: I solved this (temporarily) by making a lock that unlock on the onSuccess(). I understand that it can't be done continuously. I'm try to make the most function in 1 task as possible. Maybe I should consider split it a little bit.